# Cross Join Generating Series of Dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-join, generate-series

I am trying to count the number of tenants that renew in a month, based off of a "dtleasefrom" (lease start date). However, I want to attribute each renewal back to the month that the last lease ended, and tie it to a generated series of dates that can be used to pivot off of. However, I cannot seem to figure out why the unit_month_date doesn't equal the dtleaseto date. See pictures and code below.

[image]

```
Select
ten.scode as leasename
,th.sevent as event_type
,th.dtoccurred as date_occurred
,unit.scode as unit
,p.scode as property
,th.dtapply as apply_date
,th.dtapprove as approve_date
,th.dtsigndate as sign_date
,th.dtmovein as move_in_date
,th.dtmoveout as move_out_date
,th.dtleasefrom as lease_from
,th.dtleaseto as lease_to
,th.dtnotice as notice_date
,th.crent as rent
,att.subgroup2 as zone
,(ten.sfirstname || ' ' ||  ten.slastname) as tenant_name
,pm.property_manager as property_manager
,(case when date_trunc('month',th2.b) = dd.month::date and th2.row_numba = 1 and th.sevent = 'Lease Signed' then 1 else 0 end) as Leases_Ending
,dd.month::date as unit_month
,(case when date_trunc('month',th2.b) = dd.month::date and EXTRACT(day from age(th.dtleasefrom,th2.b)) <= 60  and EXTRACT(day from age(th.dtleasefrom,th2.b))  >= 0 and th2.row_numba = 1 and th.sevent = 'Lease Renewal' then 1 else 0 end) as Renewals
,(case when date_trunc('month',th2.b) = dd.month::date and EXTRACT(day from age(th.dtleasefrom,th2.b)) <= 60  and th2.row_numba = 1 and  th.sevent = 'Lease Renewal' then 1 else 0 end) as Renewals_All_In
,(case when th.istatus not in (1,2) and date_trunc('month',th2.b) < dd.month::date and th.sevent = 'Lease Signed'  then 1 else 0 end) as MTM_tenant
,th2.row_numba
,th.hmy
FROM
yardi.tenant ten
JOIN yardi.Tenant_History th  on ten.hmyperson = th.htent
CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series('05-01-2017'::date,'01-01-2020','1 month') as month) dd
JOIN (SELECT th.htent as a , date_trunc('month',th.dtleaseto) as b, Row_Number() over(partition by th.htent order by th.hmy) as Row_Numba FROM yardi.tenant_history th group by th.htent,th.dtleaseto,th.hmy ) th2 on th2.b = dd.month and th.htent = th2.a
JOIN yardi.unit on unit.hmy = th.hunit
JOIN yardi.property p on p.hmy = unit.hproperty
JOIN yardi.attributes att on att.hprop = p.hmy
JOIN yardi.propbut_property_management pm on pm.hcode = p.hmy

WHERE ten.istatus < 6 and th2.row_numba = 1
```

Comment: `on th2.b = dd.month and th.htent = th2.a`. In this clause you are joining solely by month and what you get seems to meet this condition. Try to add year field (`date_trunc('year',th.dtleaseto) as c`) to the subquery and add `th2.c = dd.year`

Comment: [mcve] please. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.